# Check if UIView is touched?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uipickerview

Hey, I want to be able to check if user touches my UIView so I can dismiss my picker how can I do it actually? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIView` class in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController` subclass that contains your `UIView`.  It would look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.aView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];
}
```

Then implement a handler for the tap which, based on the above code, would look like this:

```
-(void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Add in your picker dismissal code here
}
```

Hope this helps,

Justin